# How to wrap divs inside a new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to wrap the two divs `<div class="cm-cp-title">` and `<div class="cm-cp-value">` inside a div called `cm-cp-container`. Actually it is working, but it merges all together, it is shown like below after I put the `wrapAll();`

[image]

what is that issues? im wonder how to separate each of it?
Below is the result i needed,
[image]

```js
$(function() {
// document
 'use strict';

 var coupon = $('div.cm-coupon');
 
 // Settings
 coupon.each(function() {
  var _coupon = $(this);
  var cpValue = _coupon.attr("data-value") + "";
  
  // Different Data type
  if (_coupon.data('type') == "c1") 
  {
   _coupon.addClass('red').css(
    {
     "background" : "black",
     "display": "table"}
    );
   _coupon.append(
    '<div class="cm-cp-title">' + 'black here' + '</div>' + '\n' + '<div class="cm-cp-value">' + cpValue + '</div>'
    );
  } 

  else if (_coupon.data('type') == "c2") 
  {
   _coupon.addClass('green').css(
    {
     "background" : "green",
     "display": "table"}
    );
   _coupon.append('<div class="cm-cp-title">'+ 'green here' + '</div>' + '\n' + '<div class="cm-cp-value">' + cpValue + '</div>');
  } 

  else if (_coupon.data('type') == "c3") 
  {
   _coupon.addClass('blue').css(
    {
     "background" :"blue",
     "display": "table"}
    );
   _coupon.append('<div class="cm-cp-title">'+ 'blue here' + '</div>' + '\n' + '<div class="cm-cp-value">' + cpValue + '</div>');
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 });

 $('.cm-cp-title, .cm-cp-value').wrapAll("<div class='cm-cp-container'/>");
  
 // alignment to middle
 $('.cm-coupon').on('resize',function() {
  $(".cm-cp-container").css('margin-top', function() {
   return($('.cm-coupon').height() - $(this).height()) / 2
  });
 }).resize();
});//end
```

```css
.cm-coupon {
 width: 340px;
 height: 156px;
 float: left;color: #fff;
 margin: 0 10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="c1" data-value="50"></div>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="c2" data-value="20"></div>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="c3" data-value="70"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: edit the question ady,you can check the code snippet again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working Snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  var coupon = $('div.cm-coupon');
  var colors = new Map([["c1", "black"], ["c2", "green"], ["c3", "blue"]]);
 
  // Settings
  coupon.each(function() {
    var _coupon = $(this);
    var cpValue = _coupon.attr("data-value") + "";
    var color = colors.get(_coupon.data('type'));

    _coupon.addClass(color).css({
      "background" : color,
      "display": "table"
    });
    
    _coupon.append('<div class="cm-cp-title">' + color + ' here' + '</div>' + '\n' + '<div class="cm-cp-value">' + cpValue + '</div>');

    $(_coupon.children()).wrapAll("<div class='cm-cp-container'/>");
  });
  
  // alignment to middle
  $('.cm-coupon').on('resize',function() {
    $(".cm-cp-container").css('margin-top', function() {
      return($('.cm-coupon').height() - $(this).height()) / 2
    });
  }).resize();
});//end
```

```css
.cm-coupon {
  width: 340px;
  height: 156px;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="c1" data-value="50"></div>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="c2" data-value="20"></div>
<div class="cm-coupon" data-type="c3" data-value="70"></div>
```

### Explanation :

- **First**
  I reduced the code removing the `if` statements because the only difference between the blocks `if/else/else` was the color `("black"/"green"/"blue")`. I used a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead, to switch the value of the color according to the type.

  What I did:

  ```
  var colors = new Map([["c1", "black"], ["c2", "green"], ["c3", "blue"]]);
  coupon.each(function () {
    var _coupon = $(this);
    var color = colors.get(_coupon.data('type'));
  ```

  And then use `color` where need to.

---

- **Second**
  The problem you are encoutering is because you are not wrapping all the divs into the container, but wrapping the children of the divs.

  So

  ```
  $('.cm-cp-title, .cm-cp-value').wrapAll("<div class='cm-cp-container'/>");
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  $(coupon).wrapAll("<div class='cm-cp-container'/>");
  ```

---

**EDIT :**
It seems like you want to wrap the inner elements of the coupons instead.

Then use `_coupon.children()` instead, like this

```
$(_coupon.children()).wrapAll("<div class='cm-cp-container'/>");
```

and move it inside the `each` loop.

I edited the snippet. you can check.

In fact, the way you did it in your code, it is selecting **all the matching elements in the document** and wrapping it altogether. That is why the last two were moving inside the black div.

Comment: Please provide also an explanation so he could understand what he did wrong.

Comment: sorry but actually i need the cm-cp-container wrap between <div class="cm-cp-title"> and <div class="cm-cp-value">,not included the cm-coupon

Comment: so you'll have one `cm-cp-container` per `cm-coupon`. Is that so?

Comment: means like , <div class= "cm-coupon"> <div class="cm-cp-container">then the child div will at here which is cp-title and also cp-value </div></div>

Comment: it work nicely! thanks for the help and explanation ! ;)